# Ionic 2 - adMob - interstitial not showing up

Tags: javascript, admob, ionic2

The method `prepareInterstitial` works fine because the promise is called but when I call `showInterstitial` inside the promise, nothing is show.

What did I missed? Is is possible that it is a css issue?

Here is my code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor() {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    AdMob.onAdDismiss().subscribe(() => { 
      console.log("Add dismiss")
    });


  }
  onButtonClick(){
    AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
      adId:'xxxxxxxxx'
    }).then(() => { 
      console.log("Add loaded")
      AdMob.showInterstitial();
    }, err => {
      console.log("Add loaded err", err);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same error too. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nope... I am sorry...

Comment: Okay, I didn't find a solution, but I switched to this https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free and it works great now!